# What is the purpose of SharedPreferences in Android ?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

- What is the purpose of SharedPreferences in Android?
- Why it is used ?
- Where it want to be use?

Comment: Have you goggled?? If yes then there is no need to ask this question.

Comment: try this link you will get all information regarding sharedpreferences. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences is used to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).
for more  [visit here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

reference [earlier answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698490/what-is-the-use-of-shared-preferences-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is used to permanently store preferences in key:value pair

SharedPreferences is accessible by all the Activity(ies) of an app. Other app cannot directly access the content of shared_prefs

App stores its data/preferences in the SharedPreferences.

E.g. Say in a game u can store ur score, game level, user name, no of kill, etc  in the preferences; so that it is accessible all throughout the game; yet by that particular game only.

Game "Gold Miner 2" does it. It is only one example.

Svox tts save ANDROID_ID in preferences file;

You need to keep in mind that if u delete the app, all SharedPreferences will be deleted (/data/data//shared_prefs);

Answer (score 0):

You can read the developer android site about SharedPreference to save light data till your application exists into user's device. It will remain saved even after existing your application.

[Storage in android with SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[SharedPreference in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Hope it will help you..!!!