# Difference between preference and shared preference in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

The concept of preferences and shared preferences in Android are mixed up for me. What is the difference?

Comment: Related post - [What is the use of Shared Preferences in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15698490/465053)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html)**: The user interface part of the settings. It contains different classes which allow to composes Settings screens from code or XML. They can look like this:

[image]

**[Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)**: These are used to store values in XML files. These files are created, maintained and deleted by Android for you. They are not encrypted and [can easily be changed when the user has rooted his/her phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.simon.marquis.preferencesmanager&hl=de) (nice for development). Don't use these for sensitive information. The above mentioned *Preferences* use *Shared Preferences* as the underlying system.

Comment: Is encryption important when the app is not installed on root devices? I notice `SharedPreferences` provide a private flag to prevent other apps access. It won't be ecrypted, but other files can't access the internal files of another app, so to me, encryption is not necessary?

Answer (score 14):

What the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html) is saying:

- **android.preference** : is a **package** providing classes for preferences management ... The PreferenceScreen contains Preference elements such as a CheckBoxPreference, EditTextPreference, ListPreference, PreferenceCategory, or RingtonePreference... which means that preference is just the **UI tools**.
- All settings made for a given Preference will be automatically **saved** to the application's instance of **SharedPreferences**. Access to the SharedPreferences is simple with getSharedPreferences()... which means that this is **the way to save these preferences** ...

Answer (score 2):

To understand it in a simple way-

**SharedPreferences** is  an interface that manages a set of **Preference**s.
SharedPreferences are stored as key-value pairs and updated in memory as user interacts with them. For eg. Brightness is a Preference in Display Settings.

To get hold of all Preferences we use SharedPreferences as

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
```

whereas to handle a particular Preference we use

```
Preference p = getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(index);
```